# ComboBox printing the Object Type

Tags: c#, wpf

i'm trying to learn WPF and on top of that the MVVM style of doing things.

I have a simple practice app in which i would like to display codes in a combo box.

My Code

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace SteamCodes
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Codes> codes;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            codes = new ObservableCollection<Codes>()
            {
                new Codes() {CodeID = "1", Code="CODETEXT"}
            };
            steamCode.ItemsSource = codes.ToString();
        }
    }

    public class Codes
    {
        public string CodeID { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My XAML

```
<Window x:Class="SteamCodes.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SteamCodes"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox x:Name="steamCode" ItemsSource="{Binding Source = Codes}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="43" Margin="122,37,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="259"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

At the moment my Combo box is Pulling through as each option in the ComboBox is a letter from the line 'System.Collections.Objectmodel.ObservableCollection`1[SteamCodes.Codes]'

Everyone of those letters is a different drop down option in the combo box.

Any Ideas where i have gone wrong.

Comment: `ItemsSource` should be bound to a collection of data items. You are assigning (not binding) a string, which is a collection of characters. Your binding expression in XAML doesn't work. Read up about the basics here: [Data Binding Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Ok thank you, i will take a look at that link now.

Comment: What else should it do? You are putting your whole collection to a string. Image you would have to codes, how should the combobox decide wich one to display if the source of the item is set to two values --> CodeID and Code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `ComboBox` `ItemSource` must be a collection of items, not a string:

```
steamCode.ItemsSource = codes;
```

You also have to specify which property of your item must be considered as value to be shown in combobox by setting `DisplayMemberPath` property:

```
steamCode.DisplayMemberPath = "Code";
```

To specify which property of bound objects will be used as actual selected value you have to use `SelectedValuePath` property:

```
steamCode.SelectedValuePath = "CodeID";
```

---

The MVVM approach is this:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Codes> Codes { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<Codes>();
}
```

The MainWindow constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var viewModel = new ViewModel();
    viewModel.Codes.Add(new Codes { CodeID = "1", Code = "CODETEXT" });

    DataContext = viewModel;
}
```

The XAML:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Codes}" DisplayMemberPath="Code" .../>
```

Comment: Thats brilliant, worked a treat, hoever where is the binding in the XAML come into this as i thought that was the MVVM way to do things? if i assign steamCode.ItemsSource = codes; in the code then there is no need to bind? Many thanks fro your answer!

Comment: Yes, you don't need to set ItemsSource in your XAML because you have already done it in your code behind, which is one way of doing this. Take a look at this article to get a better idea about how DataBinding in WPF works: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29054/WPF-Data-Binding-Part

Comment: This tutorial is a good start as well: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/introduction